# Number of Channels-Matlab vs Opencv

Tags: opencv

I am using an image, the details of which I got using imfinfo in matlab are as follows:

```
Filename: 'dog.jpg'
                  FileModDate: '25-Mar-2011 15:54:00'
                     FileSize: 8491
                       Format: 'jpg'
                FormatVersion: ''
                        Width: 194
                       Height: 206
                     BitDepth: 24
                    ColorType: 'truecolor'
              FormatSignature: ''
              NumberOfSamples: 3
                 CodingMethod: 'Huffman'
                CodingProcess: 'Sequential'
                      Comment: {}
               NewSubFileType: 0
                BitsPerSample: [8 8 8]
    PhotometricInterpretation: 'RGB'
             ImageDescription: [1x13 char]
                 StripOffsets: 154
              SamplesPerPixel: 3
                 RowsPerStrip: 206
              StripByteCounts: 119892
```

It shows number of channels =3(NumberOfSamples: 3) but when I find the number of channels in opencv using the following code, I get `No. of channels = 1`

```
Mat img = imread("dog.jpg", 0);
printf("No. of Channels = %d\n", img.channels());
```

Why so?? Please explain.

Comment: imread("dog.jpg", 0); // the 0 at the end *forces* 8bit grayscale. try 1 to enforce bgr, or -1 for 'as is'

Comment: Thank You Berak. I am beginner and I have just started with Opencv today, your help appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome. just keep a link to the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread) handy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @berak commented, by using `0` as the second parameter of [`imread()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread), you are loading it as a grayscale image. Try to load it by passing it a negative value `<0` in order to return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel) or a positive value `>0` to return a 3-channel color image.

Like:

```
Mat img = imread("dog.jpg", -1); // <0 Return the loaded image as is
                            ^^
```